# Firebase, get property by email

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have this database on Firebase:

```
{
  "issues" : {
    "-L04771_EjrLlv5u1-GU" : {
      "issue" : "Test insert 1",
      "last_edit" : "d8QICgTG5xR20RBzAXfzfu8gLgw2",
      "owner" : "d8QICgTG5xR20RBzAXfzfu8gLgw2",
      "owner_email" : "example1@gmail.com",
      "status" : 1,
      "url" : "http://www.example.com/example.html"
    },
    "-L047pIoqxkj4saaTYyQ" : {
      "issue" : "Test insert 2",
      "last_edit" : "d8QICgTG5xR20RBzAXfzfu8gLgw2",
      "owner" : "d8QICgTG5xR20RBzAXfzfu8gLgw2",
      "owner_email" : "example2@gmail.com",
      "status" : 1,
      "url" : "http://www.example.com/example.html"
    }
  }
}
```

I have to extract only those who have owner_email "example1@gmail.com".

Is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Firebase Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) and especially the [equalTo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo)-Query.

Your code would be something like this:

```
// Find all issues with owner_email = example1@gmail.com
var ref = firebase.database().ref("issues");
ref.orderByChild("owner_email").equalTo("example1@gmail.com").on("value", function(snapshot) {
   // Loops through the matching issues
   snapshot.forEach(function(child) { 
      console.log(child.key); 
   });
});
```

Comment: That code will log `issues`. You'll want to loop over the results and print the child keys: `snapshot.forEach(function(child) { console.log(child.key); })`

Comment: Correct. I was focused on the query, which I think is the key part here. I edited my answer. Thanks for mentioning!